# Can i use both grant_type=password and grant_type=authorization_code in same project for oauth2 in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Please do let me know, the situation is if I use Alexa, then our project should implement `grant_type=authorization_code` and when using our own mobile app we need `grant_type=password`, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
When you store clients, you assign them the allowed grant type (e.g. password, authorization_code).

As an example, look at he following code:

```
clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
}
```

The *my-trusted-client* client can either use password or authorization code.

The snippet comes from [this guide](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-with-oauth2) that I strongly suggest you to follow together with [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs). Moreover, as a note, you should read the [OAuth2 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6749/?include_text=1). It is the best guide to understand the flow.

Comment: thna a lot, yup i tried including both in my project and both working fine independently, thnx

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, consider selecting the answer. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer